# Mod Rewrite not working as visually intended with multiple dashes (-)

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

so I'm trying to get my mod rewrite using .htaccess to work how I would like it, but this doesn't seem to be working, what I have:

```
index.php?id=concept-art-artist&artist=Marek-Okon
```

should change to:

```
concept-art-artist-Marek-Okon
```

my mod rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ /index.php?id=$1&artist=$2 [L]
```

When navigating to the new URL i get a 404 error, is it a case that Its not possible todo it this way?

Hope someone can shed some light! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)$ index.php?id=$1$2$3&artist=$4$5 [L]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, concept-art-artist is a file concept-art-artist.php, and &artist is information to parse, it doesn't seem like it likes the - in between marek-okon because it works fine if i change to marek_okon!

Comment: Do you have any other rewrite rules?